# Is there any summation method that assigns $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} =-\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I don't know too much about alternate summation methods, but am interesting to know if any give the sum of the harmonic series to be

$$-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Standard regularizations give $'\zeta(1)'=\gamma$, the Euler Mascheroni constant.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your motivation or not, but I once thought about this, and the reason was because I wanted to know if there was some kind of factorial behavior going on in the denominator. The value of $\zeta(3)$ is unknown, but even if it worked, the pattern stops there, as it does not hold for $\zeta (4)$

Comment: @OlivierOloa : ok, show us how with a 'standard regularization method' you obtain $\gamma$

Comment: Have alook here (Ramanujan summation):http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64898/values-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-and-the-ramanujan-summation-how-strong-is and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation

Comment: @AlfredYerger The motivation is for $\zeta(3)$ but mine had nothing specific to do with factorials. I'll make another post and message you.

Comment: @AlfredYerger Please share your motivation though!

Comment: $$\zeta(1)=2\beta(1)-\frac{1}{\Gamma(1)}\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac34\right)?$$

Comment: I wouldn't say it came from anything technical. I was a sophomore student, and I'd heard of the zeta function, and I was just curious if there was any kind of nice pattern. I didn't actually know how $\zeta(2)$ was even calculated at the time, so it was really just an empty conjecture.

Comment: @AlfredYerger Lol, the unsolved mysteries of math, eh?

Comment: @OlivierOloa : yes but the Ramajuan summation is by far the least common summation method, used mostly when all the other methods fail (Abel, zeta summation, Cesaro mean,...)

Comment: Maybe I should have written 'some regularizations...' This is also Sondow's regularization:)

Answer (score 0):

$$\zeta(1)=\sum_{n\ge1}^{\Re}\frac1n=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1n-\int_1^N\frac1tdt\right)=\gamma$$

It equals the Euler-Mascheroni constant by definition.

You can find the said formula and derivation [on the wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation)

And no, I do not think you can assign $-\frac\pi2$ to the series.

Comment: this is not $\zeta(1)$ but $\lim_{s \to 1} \zeta(s) - \frac{1}{s-1}$, the derivation is on wikipedia :)

Comment: @user1952009 I think that this is (exactly) the spirit: removing the divergent part.

Comment: @user1952009 Well, if you want, you can try it however you wish and post it as your answer.